# How do i add add multiple id's in 1 button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying for like an hour to find the right value to do that, and now, only 1 link is highlighted, but i want all the links to get bg's color in yellow, can someone tell me please, what i did or what i am doing wrong? idk how to put more id's in just 1 button without any extra codes...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hl(divId) {
    var div = document.getElementById(divId);
    div.className = "highlight";
}
function unhl(divId) {
    var div = document.getElementById(divId);
    div.className = "1";
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.highlight, .highlight a {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="thinger">
   Visit  <a id="1" href="https://instagram.com/">Instagram</p></a>
   <p>Visit <a id="2" href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</p></a>
        <p>Visit <a id="3" href="https://discord.gg/">Discord</p></a>
    
</div>
<button onclick="hl('1');">Highlight</button>

<button onclick="unhl('1');">Unhighlight</button>
```

Comment: Try replacing `onclick="hl('1');"'+'onclick="hl('b');"` with `onclick="hl('1'); hl('b');"`?

Comment: What would be the point. ID's are unique, you can't make something MORE unique.

Comment: You can't add add multiple id's in 1 button. You can create multiple button instances with different ids. (P.S. `<button onclick="hl('1');"'+'onclick="hl('b');">` two onclicks in one button is wrng and causes erreor

Comment: Yeah, removed that section, i tried the id's with letters, and forgot to remove that part of the code...

Comment: I want to assign more ids to 1 single button, not to make 2 clicks in a button...

Comment: Yes, but WHY? It doesn't make sense to do so.

Comment: Whats your goal? Looks like there might be a smarter solution. IDs never can be used more than one time, use classes for this.

Comment: Try this: 
`<button id="1" onclick="hl('1');">Highlight</button>`
<button id="2" onclick="unhl('2');">Unhighlight</button>`

Comment: Can you give a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish?  Is it: you want to 1. click on the `Highlight` button, and call code to set the class on all three `a` tags so that they are all highlighted ? And then 2. when you click `Unhighlight` it will remove the highlighting class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following snippet :

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a')
const btnHighlight = document.querySelector('#highlight')
btnHighlight.addEventListener('click', () => {
  links.forEach(l => l.classList.toggle('highlight'))
  links[0].classList.contains('highlight')
    ? btnHighlight.innerText = 'Unighlight' 
    : btnHighlight.innerText = 'Highlight'
})
```

```css
.highlight, .highlight a {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="thinger">
   <p>Visit <a id="1" href="https://instagram.com/">Instagram</a></p>
   <p>Visit <a id="2" href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a></p>
   <p>Visit <a id="3" href="https://discord.gg/">Discord</a></p>
</div>
<button id="highlight">Highlight</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform similar operation on all anchor elements, why not use a `className` selector instead. For instance

```js
const links = [...document.getElementsByClassName('link')];

function hl() {
  links.forEach(link => link.classList.add('highlight'));
}

function unhl() {
  links.forEach(link => link.classList.remove('highlight'));
}
```

```css
.highlight,
.highlight a {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="thinger">
  <p>Visit <a class="link" href="https://instagram.com">Instagram</a></p>
  <p>Visit <a class="link" href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></p>
  <p>Visit <a class="link" href="https://discord.gg">Discord</a></p>
</div>
<button onclick="hl()">Highlight</button>
<button onclick="unhl()">Unhighlight</button>
```

Or if you still want to use ids, call the function thrice inside `onclick`

```
<button onclick="hl('1'); hl('2'); hl('3')">Highlight</button>
```

Comment: Good answer, but based on the code in the question, the OP is quite novice to JS. I suspect your code will be difficult for OP to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class tag. Class allows to use multiple classes on a single button and the same class on multiple buttons.

You can use the following code to access every button with a class.

document.getElementsByClassName("example");

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys